# Is it inefficient to emit QByteArray?

Tags: performance, qt

My application is a network application. Its job is to receive streams of packets (QByteArray) in which I would like to emit them as signals. Would doing so be inefficient? I'm concerned with copying of large buffers.

Answer (score 13):

`QByteArray` uses [Copy-on-write](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html). Which means that only the pointer is copied around, that is, until you modify the content of the `QByteArray`. So you should be all right if you just pass it along.

Comment: And if you have already allocated the memory which you want to pass around, you can create the first QByteArray in the chain using the QByteArray::fromRawData() function.